# Problem with identifying user, Build chat app without login

Tags: cookies, jwt, chatbot, software-design

I want to build an in-app chat application without any login.
So, the user communicates with the program (the backend), not with other user. So, it's a chatbot.
My question is: How to identify the user? Should I just log the IP address? Or, should I generate a random ID on server? Or, should I just generate it on the client?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the purpose of identifying the user is for the server to keep track of who is sending the chat message and to send back the response to the appropriate client (user). IP address can't be reliably used as a way of uniquely identifying the user because of numerous reasons (it is a separate topic). One example of it would be this - A small company routes all the outgoing traffic from its office network via a single router that has a single IP address. In this case, the requests coming from different employees of that company would have same IP address as detected by the chat server. So it can't distinguish between these users.

The idea of generating unique identifier on the server for each user can work. A UUID or a JWT or something similar can be used to generate the id when the user initiates the chat for the very first time. This ID needs to be passed back to the client so that clients (users) can send the subsequent chat messages using the same ID. Thus, in this model, the client would need to have a place to store this ID so that it can keep passing it back to the server in its chat messages. Now the problem can happen when the client loses this ID. How can we recover from this situation? The answer would be similar to the approaches being used when someone loses their password. There are several recovery mechanisms such as sending the reset link on the trusted email address or sending it on user's phone as a code or generating a recovery key which is different from the ID and emailing it out to the user which can later be used to reset the ID. Basically, there should be an alternate and secure way (recovery flow) to identify the user if the ID is lost.

If the ID is generated on the client side, that can also work as long as all the clients are able to generate the ID that is guaranteed to be unique. Clients can pass in the generated ID to the server and server can check if it is already used and send a retry message to the client if it finds that it is already used. Or if the clients are using some hardware that has unique serial number and that serial number can be used to generate the ID.

In either cases, all the requests must pass in the ID to the server so that server can do the identification.

Hope this helps!